# DateTimePicker value range with Time Format

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have problem with *dataTimePicker* range. I have to make a user interface where the user can set only specific time. This range is: `22:00(10 PM) to 6:00(6AM)` next day. Only values in this range are available.

I created a control with `.MinDate = "2010-01-01 22:00"` and `.MaxDate = 2010-01-02 6:00` but when I use *dataTimePicker* with only Time Format and **UP DOWN** button there is a problem at the border of two days. When the user clicks UP arrow at 23:00 value flip to 22:00, not to 00:00 next day. The same problem is when you try input value by keyboard ex. 4:00. The control rejects this change and does not flip the day to the next one.

I've tried using the `ValueChange` event but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is it WinForms/WPF/UWP? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the Hour value doesn't change the current Day of the `DateTime` value, so you're stuck on 2 valid hours in the current date: `22.00` and `23:00`.

This is a possible workaround, adjusting manually the current `Date` value. Set:
**`DateTimePicker.Value`** to the minimum date (`01-01-2010 22:00 PM`).
**`MinDate`** value to minimum Date value only (`1/1/2010`).
**`MaxDate`** value to the maximum DateTime (`1/2/2010 6:00 AM`).
**`Format`** to `Custom`.
**`CustomFormat`** to `HH:mm`
**`dtPickerMinHour`** to the minimum accepted Hour (or use the DTP Tag or whatever)

Subscribe to the DateTimePicker's **`ValueChanged`** event:

```
int dtPickerMinHour = 22;
bool timeAdjustedByCode = false;

private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (timeAdjustedByCode) { timeAdjustedByCode = false; return; }
    var dtp = sender as DateTimePicker;
    var dt = dtp.Value;
    if (dt.Hour == 0) {
        if (dt.Date == dtp.MinDate) {
            timeAdjustedByCode = true;
            dtp.Value = dt.AddDays(1);
        }
        else {
            timeAdjustedByCode = true;
            dtp.Value = dt.AddDays(-1);
        }
    }
    else if (dt.Hour < dtPickerMinHour && dt.Date == dtp.MinDate.Date) {
        timeAdjustedByCode = true;
        dtp.Value = dt.AddHours(1);
    }
}
```